# User Inputted List of Dictionaries Python

Tags: python

So I am trying to make a list of dictionaries in python based on user input.

Each entry has Name, Price, and Category

I want to create a list of these items but am stuck as to how to go about this.

I tried the following code but its not working.

```
data = [{}]

data["Name"] = input("Enter a name: ")
data["Price"] = input("Enter a price: ")
data["Category"] = input("Enter a category: ")
```

Comment: Change `data = [{}]` to `data = {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a list with a single empty dictionary: `[{}]`. That's not going to me super useful for you. You can make a new dictionary with `{}` and append that to a list when you have populated it:

```
list_of_data = []

# maybe this part goes in a loop?
data = {}    
data["Name"] = input("Enter a name: ")
data["Price"] = input("Enter a price: ")
data["Category"] = input("Enter a category: ")

print(data)
# A single dictionary like:
# {'Name': 'Top', 'Price': '5.0', 'Category': 'Toy'}  

list_of_data.append(data)

print(list_of_data)
# your list with it's new element (the dictionary) like:
# [ {'Name': 'Top', 'Price': '5.0', 'Category': 'Toy'} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = []

name = str(input("Enter a name: "))
price = str(input("Enter a price: "))
category = str(input("Enter a category: "))
data.append({"Name": name, "Price": price, "Category": category})
```

Comment: You should explain what you are doing rather than just posting code.

Comment: Sorry guys, my bad. I guees the mistake was start the list with a void dict() and try fill it after. What I did was start a void list, get the input values and finally I config a dict () with those values to apend it into list

Answer (score 0):

So what you are trying to do is index a list with strings. Since data is a LIST of dicts.

The better way of doing this would be, 
 1. create a list
 2. create a dictionary
 3. input into dictionary
 4. add dictionary to the list

like so...

```
data = []
dataDict = dict()
dataDict["Name"] = input("Enter a name: ")
dataDict["Price"] = input("Enter a price: ")
dataDict["Category"] = input("Enter a category: ")
data.append(dataDict)
```